# How to read data from text file with comma separated values and insert into temp table using in stored procedure

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

FIle name `emp.txt` - the text file contains data like this:

```
emp_no,emp_EXPIRY_DATE,STATUS
a123456,2020-07-12,A
a123457,2020-07-12,A
```

I want to insert data into a temp table using a stored procedure.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i want to read data from text file and insert in to the table using storeprocedure

Comment: bulk INSERT  dummyTest.TEMP_ORG_DTLS12  (emp_no,emp_EXPIRY_DATE,STATUS) 
   FROM 'D:emp.TXT'
   WITH 
      (
        FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
        ROWTERMINATOR ='\n'
      )

Answer (score 0):

Which database do you use? "Oracle" SQL Developer looks like "Oracle" (of course), but - code you posted as a comment isn't Oracle.

Anyway, if it was, then doing what you plan to do would require `UTL_FILE` package. CSV file should be put into a directory (usually on the database server) which is a *source* for directory (as an Oracle object); user that is supposed to load data should have read (and write?) privileges on it.

Alternatively, you could use the CSV file as an **external table**. That option might be simpler as it allows you to write *ordinary* `SELECT` statements against it, i.e. *read* data from it and *insert* into the target table that resides in an Oracle database. This option also requires the "directory" stuff.

Or, if you want to do that locally, consider using **SQL*Loader**; create a control file and load data. This option might be extremely fast, way faster than previous options. You won't see any difference for small files, but - for a lot of data - this might be your choice.

---

A SQL*Loader example:

Test table:

```
SQL> create table test
  2    (emp_no          varchar2(10),
  3     emp_expiry_date date,
  4     status          varchar2(1));

Table created.
```

Control file:

```
options (skip=1)
LOAD DATA
infile emp.txt
replace
INTO TABLE test
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
  emp_no,
  emp_expiry_date "to_date(:emp_expiry_date, 'yyyy-dd-mm')",
  status
)
```

Loading session & the result:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_Format = 'yyyy-mm-dd';

Session altered.

SQL> $sqlldr scott/tiger control=test13.ctl log=test13.log

SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Sri Pro 11 21:02:44 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Commit point reached - logical record count 1
Commit point reached - logical record count 2

SQL> select * from test;

EMP_NO     EMP_EXPIRY S
---------- ---------- -
a123456    2020-12-07 A
a123457    2020-12-07 A

SQL>
```

Comment: i am using oracle sql developer in local



bulk INSERT dummyTest.TEMP_ORG_DTLS12
 (emp_no,emp_EXPIRY_DATE,STATUS) FROM 'D:emp.TXT' 
WITH ( FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR ='\n' )



what is the issue on this code

Comment: can please give example use my file name

Comment: I edited my answer and added a SQL*Loader example. By the way, what's wrong with your code? it is **wrong**, that's what's wrong with it. I've never seen syntax like this. Where did you find it?